# Cyclic dependency issue in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developed a custom error handler which implements Angular2 Error Handler class. My custom error handler uses a logger service to log errors. The code looks like as follows:

```
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private logger: LoggerService) {}

    handleError(error: any): void {
        logger.error('....');
    }
}
```

However, since the logger service uses Angular2 router, I cannot inject the logger service to the custom error handler! Running the above code throws the following exception!
`Error: Provider parse errors:↵Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!`

Comment: Why does logger service use router? there are no routes involved with service. Services are supposed to be singletons.

Comment: It's because our logger service uses a remote logger to send logs to another online service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject manually, to avoid the cyclic dependency problem because this class is created before the providers, your code should be:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Logger } from '...';

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    handleError(error: any): void {
        const logger = this.injector.get(Logger);
        logger.error('....');
    }
}
```